# What is Repeater Tasks process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, repeater

I was working on a ASP.NET web forms project and was trying to attach a data source to a repeater using wizard. My Visual Studio window suddenly hanged for some seconds and during that time I saw a popup minimized window:
[image].

Can someone please tell me what it is? And why its showing default icon of Windows Forms? Is it some internal process of Visual Studio?

Comment: Did you happen to hit the green play icon or press F5 by chance?

Comment: No it happened when I was  configuring the data source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a background task that Visual Studio uses to Scaffold your code to ensure that the dots are connected when creating a data source.

The gist is that it runs through your code, checks objects for links to your data source, and sets up the settings you've added in the wizard.